# java.sqlexception:no suitable driver found for root

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

He creado un programa en java que crea una conexión a la base de datos y me salta el error `java.sqlexception:no suitable driver found for root`.

No sé de donde me puede venir el error y necesito ayuda.

Os muestro mi código abajo:

```
package principal;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.util.logging.Level;

import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class conexion {

    private String cadenaconecion="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/cafeteria";

    private String usuario ="root";

    private String contrasena="";

    private Connection con =null;

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException 
    {

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
               con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(usuario, cadenaconecion,contrasena);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,ex);
            }


            return con;
        }
}
```

Comment: les dejo mi codigo para que me digan cual es el error

Comment: Estás pasando algunos parámetros al revés al método `getConnection`, el primer parámetro debe ser `cadenaconexion`, luego `user` y luego `contrasena`. Prueba así: **`con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(cadenaconecion,usuario,contrasena);`** Si no funciona, es posible que debas añadir el puerto en el que corre mysql, por ejemplo: `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/cafeteria`. En las versiones modernas de JDBC, no es necesario usar `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`, lo puedes omitir si estás usando JDBC 4 o superior.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Parece que estas omitiendo o te falta el puerto en tu String de connection, en el siguiente ejemplo el puerto es 3306

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String connection = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YourDBName";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connection, user, password);
    if (!con.isClosed()) {
      con.close();
    }
  }
}
```